# How to Compare two arrays and move records to the bottom?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I do this in a god performance way? I have two arrays of user emails like these:

```
$a = array ('ad@d.com', 'ac@d.com', 'ab@d.com', 'aa@d.com');
$b = array ('ac@d.com', 'ab@d.com');
```

So I need to compare the two array and move records from B if exists to the bottom, so resulting array should be:

```
$c = array( 'ad@d.com','aa@d.com','ac@d.com', 'ab@d.com');
```

Of course this is an example array, maybe mine got 1000 records, that's why I want to do it only if it's cheap and not a waste of resources.
Thanhs!

Comment: Your expected output doesn't makes sense, it's just the array $a ?!

Comment: It's not the same. But I also don't see any pattern in it.

Comment: @MightyPork Only the order is different, but same values

Comment: @chifliiiii why did you ask if you don't care about answers??

Comment: @Rizier123 maybe I formulated wrong the question. But I want array B values taken from A and placed at the end.

Comment: @MightyPork is not that I don't care about answers , I got a life, so I check answers when I got time.

Comment: mhmm whatever. Just that if you clarified it when we sent the comments, you'd have answer in just a few minutes (which you had anyway, just didn't check.... nvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the ordering you want:

```
$c = array_reverse(array_unique(array_reverse(array_merge($a, $b))));
```

Here is a **more efficient** solution:

```
$c = array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), $b);
```

You can also wrap that in `array_unique()` if there is a chance of duplicate entries which you want to avoid.

If you didn't care about ordering, just `$c = $a + $b;` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @MightyPork, that's exactly what I looking for, simple and elegant solution

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `array_merge` and `array_unique` function like this:

```
$c = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b))
```

This will use the elements in  `$a` and adds the element from `$b` which are not in `$b`.